# Mutt: Goobook Installation OK, but then it does not work

Tags: gmail, mutt

I run debian stretch on my box. Until a few days ago, everything was fine with my mutt+goobook+gmail, but recently I have experienced some problems.
I tried reinstalling goobook and apparently that works fine

```
$ sudo pip install goobook
Collecting goobook
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson>=2.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages    /simplejson-3.16.0-py2.7.egg (from goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client>=1.6.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/google_api_python_client-1.7.4-py2.7.egg (from goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.7.egg (from goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2>=0.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_auth_httplib2-0.0.3-py2.7.egg (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_auth-1.5.1-py2.7.egg (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.9.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2dev,>=1.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uritemplate-3.0.0-py2.7.egg (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rsa-4.0-py2.7.egg (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->goobook)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cachetools-2.1.0-py2.7.egg (from google-auth>=1.4.1->google-api-python-client>=1.6.4->goobook)
Installing collected packages: goobook
Successfully installed goobook-3.1
```

but then for instance

```
$ goobook reload
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/goobook", line 7, in <module>
 from goobook.application import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goobook/application.py", line 21, in <module>
 import goobook.config
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goobook/goobook.py", line 99
  print("-------------------------", file=out)
                                   ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anybody else experience that? Any idea about how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Installed it using python3 and it worked.

```
python3 -m pip install goobook
```